# More than just Title and Snippet in a Marker Custom InfoWindow

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I plot markers according to lat and lon that I receive from a web API through a JSON response.

The problem is that every marker has its own data set, for example each marker has an ID, code, phone number, and name. I would like to show all if this data in each Marker's InfoWindow using a custom InfoWindowAdapter, but I am unable to show relevant data that was received in the JSON.

Here is what I have tried so far. In this code, all marker snippet contain same data, and I want to add different data into this snippet for each Marker:

```
 private class GetFixture extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {


        ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
        Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_ITEMS);
        String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS, ServiceHandler.GET);
        // print the json response in the log
        Log.d("Get match fixture resps", "> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                Log.d("try", "in the try");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                // Getting JSON Array node
                for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Double matchId = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(TAG_MATCHID));
                    Log.d("matchId", String.valueOf(matchId));
                    Double teamA = Double.valueOf(c.getString(TAG_TEAMA));
                    Log.d("teamA", String.valueOf(teamA));
                     teamB = c.getString(TAG_TEAMB);
                    Log.d("teamB", teamB);
                    //  hashmap for single match

                    HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, String> cc = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_MATCHID, String.valueOf(matchId));
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMA, String.valueOf(teamA));
                    areahash.put(TAG_TEAMB, teamB);

                    matchFixtureList.add(new LatLng(matchId, teamA));
                    cc.put(TAG_TEAMB,teamB);
                    area.add(teamB);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        int x;
        //for (LatLng point : matchFixtureList) {
        //for (String a:area)
        for ( i = 0; i < matchFixtureList.size(); i++) {

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(matchFixtureList.get(i)).title(area.get(i)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(matchFixtureList.get(i), 15));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());



            // Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.check, null);
                        TextView ashid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ash_id);
                        TextView ashcode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ash_code);
                        TextView Cellno = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell_id);
                        TextView Ashname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ash_name);

                        TextView NIC = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nic_id);
                        TextView tvlat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lat_id);
                        TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lonti_id);
                        TextView Zmid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ZM_id);




                        LatLng ll = marker.getPosition();
                        ashid.setText(marker.getTitle());
                        tvlat.setText(""+ll.latitude);
                        tvLng.setText("" + ll.longitude);

                        Zmid.setText("" + ll.longitude);
                        NIC.setText(""+ll.latitude);
                        Ashname.setText("" + ll.longitude);
                        Cellno.setText(""+ll.latitude);
                        ashid.setText("" + ll.longitude);
                        ashcode.setText(teamB);

                        ashcode.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                        return v;
                    }
                });


            }

            // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pakistan).title("Marker in pakistn"));
            //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            // mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
            // Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
            // mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
            //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(matchFixtureList(i)));
            //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5));


        }
    }
```

[image of snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60znX.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store more data points than just the title and snippet, the best way to solve this is to use a wrapper class to store the data for each `Marker`, and then keep the data stored in a `HashMap` with the Marker ID as the key so that you can obtain it in the `InfoWindowAdapter`.

First, create a holder class for the info corresponding to each `Marker` (you can expand on this to include more info as needed):

```
public class MarkerHolder {
    public String mAshId;
    public String mAshCode;
    public String mCellId;
    public String mAshName;

    public MarkerHolder(String ashId, String ashCode, String cellId, String ashName) {
        mAshId = ashId;
        mAshCode  = ashCode;
        mCellId = cellId;
        mAshName = ashName;
    }
}
```

Then create a `HashMap<String, MarkerHolder>` that will map each Marker ID to the data for each `Marker`, and make it an instance variable of the Activity:

```
HashMap<String, MarkerHolder> markerHolderMap = new HashMap<String, MarkerHolder>();
```

When you add each Marker, add an entry in the HashMap as well with a MarkerHolder object that stores all the data associated with this Marker:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(matchFixtureList.get(i)).title(area.get(i)).snippet("snipp works"));

// Assuming these parameters come from your JSON:
MarkerHolder mHolder = new MarkerHolder(ashId, ashCode, cellId, ashName);

// Then add this holder reference to the HashMap
markerHolderMap.put(marker.getId(), mHolder);
```

Then, in the `InfoWindowAdapter`,  use the info obtained from the `MarkerHolder` which was obtained from the `HashMap`:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.check, null);
        TextView ashid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ash_id);
        TextView ashcode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ash_code);
        TextView cellNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell_id);
        TextView ashName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ash_name);

        //Get the MarkerHolder for this Marker:
        MarkerHolder markerHolder = markerHolderMap.get(arg0.getId());

        //Use the data to populate the layout:
        ashid.setText(markerHolder.mAshId);
        ashcode.setText(markerHolder.mAshCode);
        cellNo.setText(markerHolder.mCellId);
        ashName.setText(markerHolder.mAshName);

        //...........

        return v;
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you sir i understand little bit i past my all code please check this and help me to put these things. please sir its my assignment and today is last date

Comment: @naveedabbas I tailored this example very close to your code, but I also want to keep this answer as generic as possible in order to help other people as well.  There is more than enough info here to solve your problem, you just need to extend this example to display all of the data from your JSON.

Comment: @naveedabbas Also, one more thing.  don't call `mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()` inside a loop, it only needs to be called once.